# Is there a kind aphorism for someone who has made a mistake, been forgiven, but shouldn't be given responsibility?

Tags: aphorism, aphorism-requests

I'm trying to explain a situation where a person has made a mistake. They have made up for their mistake. They have been forgiven. The wise boundary is not to give them responsibility for the area in which they made a mistake.

I've come up with a few examples that don't quite work:

> Putting the chocolate thief in charge of the lolly jar

This is snappy, but *thief* implies larceny which isn't appropriate.

> Putting the fox in charge of the henhouse.

This is the classic one. *Fox* implies a defective character which is mean and isn't the case here.

> Putting the person who dropped the Ming Vase in charge of the China Shop.

This is kind, and almost works because *dropping* something is a mistake. But it isn't snappy.

My question is: **Is there a kind aphorism for someone who has made a mistake, been forgiven, but shouldn't be given responsibility?**

Comment: chocolate thief and lolly jar is not great.

Answer (score 1):

"Forgiven but not forgotten. "

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask the devil to pray for your life.

Here the devil is in a state of forgiven but we all know it wants your life.